# Why does Matplotlib locator_params hides negative labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm using "matplotlib locator_params" to reduce the frequency of theta axis labels in the following plot:
[image]
Using this line of code:

```
ax.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=30)
```

works fine, but the negative labels are hidden. The result is below:
[image]
How to show back the negative labels ?

Also, how to reduce the number of labels in the r (longitude) direction ? replacing the parameter axis by y instead of x didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a polar plot, that theta axis always goes from 0 to 2 pi. You can define your own `FixedLocator` to set to the axis.

```
loc = matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, 30, endpoint=False))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
```

You can then change the ticklabels

```
ticks = -(np.roll(np.linspace(-np.pi/2,np.pi/2, 30, endpoint=False), -15)*180/np.pi)
ticker= matplotlib.ticker.FixedFormatter(ticks)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker)
```

Comment: Thanks. Concerning my second question above, do you know why: `ax.locator_params(axis='y', nticks=3)` don't work ?

Comment: You mean `nbins = 3`? The Locator on the axis is a `RadialLocator`, which uses an `AutoLocator`, which subclasses `MaxNLocator`. Therefore you can use `ax.yaxis.get_major_locator().base.set_params(nbins=3)` to set the number of locations.

Comment: Thank you so much.